# Regular expression with white space optional

Tags: regex

I'm trying to build a simple regex to match:

call name home or call name mobile

I'm using:

```
call (.*) (?:home|mobile)?
```

since the home or mobile is optional. The problem is the white-space between (.*) and the optional part. This expression doesn't match "call joe" because it requires a final blank. How can I modify it in order to take into account the optional blank?

Comment: `?` following a character or modifier makes it options, same as `{0,1}`. So, `call (.*) ?(?:home|mobile)`

Comment: The question is not clear, please supply valid and invalid sample input, and specify exact requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^call +(.+)(?: +(?:home|mobile))?$
```

i.e. include space before `home` or `mobile` also in optional part. Also it is advisable to use anchors `^` and `$` to avoid matching unwanted text.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I replace the white space with your expression, a statement like "call joe home1" is matched ;(

Comment: Can the middle part i.e name contain whitespace also like `Call Mr Bob Smith home`?

Comment: Yep it could contain whitespaces as well

Comment: Well it then it will match `joe home1` as well since that can be a valid name also

Comment: That's completely correct as per your requirements. It's not hard to allow for trailing garbage but where do you draw the line? Is "Big Homer" a name, or a name with "home" and trailing garbage?

Answer (score 1):

regular expressions allow you to tell it how many characters to look for through modifiers. Most everyone is familiar with `*` meaning `0 or more`; seems like you're looking for `?` which means `0 or 1`, same as `{0,1}`.

```
call (.*) ?(?:home|mobile)?
```

You've applied it at the end, you just also want to apply it to the space.

Comment: Ok, that's a different type of question, just need to keep learning regular expressions. Add `$` to the end.